# how can I show a list of names from my database in Swing Control "Item" in Java netbeans

Tags: java, swing

I am thinking if it is possible to show an item in java swing controls "item".

What I want to do is to show Names from my database in a java swing controls "Item" so user can choose among the lists who's information they want to see.

Is this possible?

something like this:

[image]

Comment: Hmm... I'm not aware of any visual Swing component named "Item". What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @sir Bogdan... i've seen it at the palette in jDialog Form, it was named as an "Item" under Swing Controls... please help... or should i just used textfield and display all info's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your image you have a JList. I recommend looking at the [java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html); it will teach you everything you need to know about lists.

Then, if you have a specific question we'll be glad to help.

Also, I'd recommend to stay away from any visual editor (like the one in Netbeans) until you get more experience working with Swing. The generated code will only confuse you more ;)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is not a standard Swing control named Item.  If you want to display a list of names from a database and let the user choose one, there are a couple of controls that are typically used.  First a JComboBox or as your example uses a JList.

Once you has the names in the component you will have to add an ActionListener to capture the user's selection if you want something to automatically happen once they choose a name.

Answer (score 0):

As jzd said a combobox will do what you need.Simply check whats the  index of  selected item from combobox when button is pressed and show the info for that choice .Also a component you might want to look at for displaying database information is JTable. This will produce a table with row and columns clearly shown that makes it good to diplay lots of information like name,address,phone etc.